# How do I connect to network in Fortran?

Tags: networking, fortran

I found [a 1971 document](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc119.pdf) about Fortran communication with network using slightly low-level send and receive. Admittedly Fortran changed, 1977, 1990, 2003, 2008 versions came out. Is there a standard modern interface for talking to a network? HTTP and IRC protocols are of interest.

Answer (score 7):

Fortran is just a language.  It will support any network protocol if someone has written a library for it.

For IRC try libircclient from http://www.ulduzsoft.com/linux/libircclient/.

For HTTP, try libcurl from http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/.

Use a Fortran compiler with C bindings to interface to the libraries

Comment: What sort of network are you trying to connect to and what protocol do you wish to use?  There are hundreds of protocols.  Which compiler/OS are you using?  Is it TCP or UDP, unicast, broadcast or multicast?

Comment: TCP. IRC and HTTP protocols are of interest.

Comment: Try http://www.ulduzsoft.com/libircclient/.  Suggest you use a Fortran compiler with C bindings.  Use libcurl for http.